# Removing horizontal lines and adding page number to cover letter template

Tags: page-numbering, templates, rules

I would like to use [Matthew Miller's LaTeX template for cover letters](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/long-lined-cover-letter), but since my cover letter is about 2 pages long, I need to do the following:

1. Remove the horizontal line at the end of each page.
2. Add page numbers to each page.

Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: The link to his template is here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/long-lined-cover-letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create your own template, as the letter classes in general are difficult to bend to your will. It's easy and now allows down-to-earth flexibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}\sloppy% Just for this example

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,array}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Page number in footer centre
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set general page style to fancy

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Page number in footer centre
  \fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
      \includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image} \\% Header image
      \hline
    \end{tabular}}}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}% First page has a plain page style

\usepackage{charter}% Use the Charter font for the document text
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Typical of letters
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  \today \\[12pt] % Date
  123 Broadway \\ % Address
  City, State 12345 \\
  Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\ % Phone number
  Email: john@smith.com % Email address
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Mrs. Jane Smith \\ % Addressee of the letter above the to address
  Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
  The Corporation \\
  123 Pleasant Lane \\
  City, State 12345
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs. Smith, % Greeting text

\bigskip

\lipsum[1-10]

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Sincerely yours, \\[5\normalbaselineskip]% Closing text
  John Smith
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```